# Getting an error with jQuery hide function

Tags: jquery, html

Ive been trying to get this to work but it keeps giving me an error. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZUmM/

Hopefully Im not completely screwing this up.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showIt').click(function() {
        $('#otherObject').hide();
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
     <section id="main">
        <header>

        </header>
        <article>
            <a id="showIt" href="">Show only one</a>
        </article>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </section>
    <section id="otherObject">
        <header>

        </header>
        <article>
            <img src="tdk.jpg">
        </article>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </section>
    <section id="otherObjectTwo">
        <header>

        </header>
        <article>

        </article>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </section>
    <section id="otherObject3">
        <header>

        </header>
        <article>

        </article>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </section>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to `return false;` on the link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showIt').click(function() {
        $('#otherObject').hide();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: It's also worth understanding what `return false` actually does re: bubbling. As opposed to `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking on an `<a>` tag, and then following its link.  You need to prevent the browser from following the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showIt').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#otherObject').hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your link is actually still using its expecting functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showIt').click(function() {
        $('#otherObject').hide();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

You'll want to `return false` on the a/link to prevent the default and thus the link will not follow to the url adding in the a/link.